# How to upgrade database from sql server 2000 to sql server 2014 version

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

I have database in sql server 2008 R2 version. Now, I took backup of this database and restored that on Sql server 2014. But some of the database queries are not looking compatible to new version. For example *= operator giving error in sql server 2014 version. I don't want to change each query where I get issue. Is there any way to upgrade the older version of Sql server backup to work with newer version of database? Please help.

Comment: The old join syntax has been removed already over a decade ago, maybe you should update it already? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144262%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: The reason it works in your 2008 is compatibility level you're using, but 2014 doesn't support anymore: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx

Comment: So, how can I resolve these compatibility issues in 2014 version.

Comment: Fix your code. There is no other option.